# Finding all methods that hasn't log inside try catch with NDepend

Tags: ndepend

I'm refactoring an existing application and I have got a per class instance in the form

```
private readonly ILog log; //(Log4net, but the namespace isn't
```

I've got some method in the form

```
 public  List<Nofity> GetXXX(string codice)
    {
        try
        {
               [code]

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I need to find the methods that haven't got

```
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
```

Is it possible with NDepend?

I also wish to find all the try catch method that swallow the exception

```
catch()
{
}
```

How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: With NDepend you can check if a method is calling another one, but you cannot check if this call is done in a try a catch or a finally clause.

Comment: Ok but is there a way I can know if a method is under try catch and also is calling the Log.xxx, it would be just a point to look at

Comment: No you cannot check if a call is done in a try a catch or a finally clause

Comment: I can't even check if there's a try catch clause?

Comment: Not at this point, this possibility will be soon added